# pyspark .show() works but .collect() does not

Tags: pyspark

I have a very simple pyspark program that uses dataframe to query data from a group of ORC files. I am using anaconda python in windows and installed pyspark on it.

The program goes like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark_session = SparkSession.builder.appName("test").getOrCreate()
df_orc = spark_session .read.orc("./raw_data/")
df_orc.createOrReplaceTempView("orc")
```

This works fine:

```
spark.sql("select count(*) from orc").show()
```

But this will generate errors:

```
spark.sql("select count(*) from orc").collect()
```

The error messages are:

```
WARN Utils: Truncated the string representation of a plan since it was too large. This behavior can be adjusted by setting 'spark.debug.maxToStringFields' in SparkEnv.conf.

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o81.collectToPython.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getClassReader(ClosureCleaner.scala:46)
        at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.sca
        at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.sca
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:103)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:103)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:230)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1.foreach(HashMap.scala:103)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
        at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3.visitMethodInsn(ClosureCleaner.scala:426)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.sc
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:156)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2294)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2068)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2094)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:936)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:935)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:278)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply$mcI$sp(Dataset.scala:2808)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2805)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2805)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2828)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectToPython(Dataset.scala:2805)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Does `df_orc.count()` work?

Comment: No. Similar error messages.

Comment: One more observation: the same code works fine in ubuntu linux, also with anaconda python.

Comment: maybe it's your java version problem. There seems something wrong with collect() on java 13 or 14. ==

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this works fine:

`spark.sql("select count(*) from orc").show()`

> is because `.show()` only works on the **first 5 rows of your data**

but when you run:

`spark.sql("select count(*) from orc").collect()`

> `.collect()` will work on **all your data**

from your error message:

`WARN Utils: Truncated the string representation of a plan since it was too large. This behavior can be adjusted by setting 'spark.debug.maxToStringFields' in SparkEnv.conf.`

According to the [spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/util/Utils.html):

> The performance overhead of creating and logging strings for wide schemas can be large. To limit the impact, we bound the number of fields to include by default. This can be overriden by setting the 'spark.debug.maxToStringFields' conf in SparkEnv.

Howeevr, it might affect the performance of your job, so you need something like:

```
spark = SparkSession 
.builder 
.master('local[*]') 
.appName('Notebook') 
.config('spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields', 200) 
.getOrCreate()
```

This is a new SQL config `spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields` that controls maximum number fields up to which `truncatedString` cuts its input sequences.

Default value is: `DEFAULT_MAX_TO_STRING_FIELDS = 25`

You can also add `spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields=100` to `spark-defaults.conf`

Previous versions of Spark used `spark.debug.maxToStringFields` instead of `spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields`